# Is there a python library to create github pull-request

Tags: python, git, github

I'm trying to create pull request from python, it doesn't seem to work with the `gitpython`. The checkout, creating branch, commit and push is working fine, however the pull request doesn't seem to work. After some quick search I found the [hub](https://hub.github.com/) is the cli to create pull requests. Is there a python API for creating pull request. Here is my code so far.

```py
from git import Repo
import git

Repo.clone_from(url='git@github.com:Amjad/test_repo.git', to_path='./test_repo')
git_branch = "test7"
git_repo = Repo("./test_repo")
git_repo.git.checkout("-b", git_branch)
git_repo.git.status()
shutil.copy("./ps.txt", "./test_repo/ps.txt")
git_repo.git.add("ps.txt")
git_repo.git.commit(m="first test push")
git_repo.git.push('--set-upstream', 'origin', git_branch)
git_repo.git.request_pull(git_branch, 'git@github.com:Amjad/test_repo.git', "master")
```

Comment: Can you just run the shell commands from python using the `os` or `subprocess` modules? Does an API provide you with any benefits?

Comment: You can find github libraries [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/libraries/).

Comment: You can create pull requests, as long as you keep in mind that `github != git`, and that pull requests are service-specific (meaning that on gitlab or bitbucket there would likely be different ways to create them)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pull requests are on a per-service basis. Meaning that you won't have a command to make one from a generic git library, but you can make them using whichever remote API (REST http, etc.) to create a pull request.

For example, with GitHub, you can [make pull requests with the REST API.](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/)

Comment: Indeed, using `requests` to hit the API directly, either v3 ("REST") or v4 (GraphQL) is not complicated. You can also manage repositories and interact with the git objects via the API, though that's probably to be reserved for relatively simple operations as the "git objects" API is very low-level and thus requires lots of calls for anything complex.